# clearing a output result and reusing the result

Tags: python

I am working on creating a Calculator i want to be able to ask the user if he wants to clear the result or reuse the result with a second number to create a new result. any tips or help is appreciated

```py
def cally():
    op = input('''Please type in the math operation you would like to complete:
+ for addition
- for subtraction
* for multiplication
/ for division
''')

    n1 = float(input('Please enter the first number: '))
    n2 = float(input('Please enter the second number: '))

    if op == '+':
        print(n1 + n2)

    elif op == '-':
        print(n1 - n2)

    elif op == '*':
        print(n1 * n2)
    elif op == '/':
        print(n1 / n2)

    else:
        print('You have not typed a valid operator')
cally()

def again():


    calc_again = input("Do you want to calculate again?Please type Y for YES or N for NO.")

    if calc_again == 'Y':
        cally()

    elif calc_again == 'N':
        print('See you later.')

    else:
        again()
cally()
```

Comment: Shouldnt you call the `again()` function instead

Comment: Can you please post what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Modify `cally()` to add an optional argument which is the previous result.  If this argument is present, use it as `n1` instead of prompting.  Also return the current result after printing it.

Then, after you call `cally()`, save its result in a variable, and if the user says they want to reuse the last result, pass that same variable back in to the next call to `cally()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can combine them into the same function and feed the previous result into the next operation as follows:

```
def cally(last_result=None):
    op = input('''Please type operator''')

    if last_result:
        n1=float(last_result)
    else:
        n1 = float(input('Please enter the first number: '))

    n2 = float(input('Please enter the second number: '))

    if op == '+':
        res = (n1 + n2)

    elif op == '-':
        res = (n1 - n2)

    elif op == '*':
        res = (n1 * n2)
    elif op == '/':
        res = (n1 / n2)

    else:
        print('You have not typed a valid operator')
        return

    print(res)

    calc_again = input("Do you want to calculate again? Please type Y for YES or N for NO.")

    if calc_again == 'Y':
        cally(res)

    elif calc_again == 'N':
        print('See you later.')

cally()
```

EDIT - just saw John Gordon's answer, this is basically an implementation of it